# Creating RSA-SHA1 signed SOAP Envelopes with PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I need to send SOAP messages to a slightly paranoid server that requires both SSL (seems easy enough) and each request to be signed as mentioned.

PHP's SoapClient class doesn't seem to have any signing functionality built in - what's the suggested way of doing this?

Comment: AFAIK the signature needs to be sent as a SOAP header. You can use `SoapHeader` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the SOAP-WSE library for this - it handles the signature creating and appropriate header construction into the bargain.